# Sparse matrix output to csv

Tags: csv, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix `z` that is a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` and has shape `(n,m)` where `n<<m`.  I also have labels `l` which is simply a `np.array` of strings with size `n`.

What I'd like to do is make a csv file with the "ragged" version of the data.  i.e. all of the nonzero vlaues in `z[0]` would go in a column of the csv file with a header value `l[0]`, but each column would have a different number of values.  Unfortunately `numpy` doesn't deal with ragged arrays well and I'm not sure what would be an elegant way to construct it.

Right now I'm just doing

```
np.savetxt(pth, z.todense().T, delimiter = ",")
```

and adding the column headers manually as my next process step can handle all the zeros, but is very slow that way.

EXAMPLE:

```
z.todense()
array([[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,3,0,-6,4],
       [-1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2]])

l
array(["chan1", "chan2"])
```

What I want

```
example.csv

chan1, chan2
1,-1
-1,4
3,-2
-6,
4,
```

Comment: This needs a small examplw

Comment: Is that clearer @hpaulj?

Comment: But how can you read your example back in? Don't you need some way to know where the zeros are?

Comment: I don't need to know where the zeros are (rather, I do, but I have them in `python` - the person I give the data to, who works in `excel`, doesn't).  The next step in the process only needs the data in each row, the locations aren't important.  Basically the sparse matrix is a bunch of time histories that have had most of the time points set to zero.  I only need to pass the condensed signal.

Comment: Look at `z.tolil().data`. And write your own file. Don't try to use savetxt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [74]: from scipy import sparse

In [75]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,3,0,-6,4],
    ...:        [-1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2]])
In [76]: M
Out[76]: 
<2x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [77]: M.A
Out[77]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  3,  0, -6,  4],
       [-1,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2]], dtype=int64)
```

`lil` format gives the data by row:

```
In [78]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [79]: Ml.data
Out[79]: array([list([1, -1, 3, -6, 4]), list([-1, 4, -2])], dtype=object)
```

Now it's just a matter of writing those lists to file in the way you want:

```
In [81]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [82]: for i,j in zip_longest(*Ml.data, fillvalue=''):
    ...:     astr = '%s, %s'%(i,j)
    ...:     print(astr)
    ...:     
1, -1
-1, 4
3, -2
-6, 
4,
```

`zip_longest` is an easy way to iterate through several lists, using the longest as reference.